# Are there other Pokemon with higher spawn rates right now?

Tags: pokemon-go

[This announcement](http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-news/halloween-treats-in-pokemon-go/) states that a few Pokemon (Gastly, Drowzee, Zubat, and their evolutions) will have a hugely boosted spawn rate this week.

However, when I was out last night and today in two different locations, I saw only two Zubat, but a large number of Meowth, Cubone, and even Marowak. There must be other Pokemon that have been boosted but are not on the above list. If so, is that recorded somewhere? I'm in the southeast US if region ends up playing a factor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/halloween/), it looks like aside from the Gastly, Drowzee, and Zubat, the Meowth and Cubone lines also have a bumped spawn rate during this event.

Thus, the complete list of Pokemon with increased spawns is the following:

- 041: Zubat
- 042: Golbat
- 052: Meowth
- 092: Gastly
- 093: Haunter
- 094: Gengar
- 096: Drowzee
- 097: Hypno
- 104: Cubone
- 105: Marowak

[Here](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-10-26-pokemon-go-halloween-event-update) is another source that supports the increased spawn rate of Meowth and the Cubone line.

Note: While Meowth has increased spawns during this event, apparently, Persian does not.

Comment: In a matter of hours, I caught enough Drowzees for a Hypno and my brother caught enough Ghastlys for 2 Gengars. I can say the spawn rate has increase tremendously

Comment: Very odd, wonder why Niantic didn't mention the two extra lines

Comment: @Venomous I've only been downtown for Pokehunts once, but Zubats are spawning everywhere where I work, which is very close to downtown FW

Comment: @Wondercricket ah, I've been a couple times, and since it was before Nearby was Sightings, my entire list was just Zubat

Comment: Does this also affect spawn rates from lures and incense

Comment: @Batophobia I've been to one lure today, and it had Drowzee, Hypno, Gastly, and Haunter Pokemon only

Comment: Remember you get double candy for catching, which would also boost the ability to evolve these pokemon (6 for catching, 2 for transferring)